# C cache optimization for direct mapped cache

Tags: c, performance, caching, optimization, memory

Having some trouble figuring out the hit and miss rates of the following two snippets of code.

Given info: we have a 1024 Byte direct-mapped cache with block sizes of 16 bytes. So that makes 64 lines (sets in this case) then. Assume the cache starts empty. Consider the following code:

```
struct pos {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct pos grid[16][16];
int total_x = 0; int total_y = 0;

void function1() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
             total_x += grid[j][i].x;
             total_y += grid[j][i].y;
         }
    }
}

void function2() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
             total_x += grid[i][j].x;
             total_y += grid[i][j].y;
         }
    }
}
```

I can tell from some basic rules (i.e. C arrays are row-major order) that function2 should be better. But I don't understand how to calculate the hit/miss percentages. Apparently function1() misses 50% of the time, while function2() only misses 25% of the time.

Could somebody walk me through how those calculations work? All I can really see is that no more than half the grid will ever fit inside the cache at once. Also, is this concept easy to extend to k-way associative caches?

Thanks.

Comment: Cache misses can be very hard to predict due to effects such as prefetching and associativity. It's easier to slap on a profiler and count them from the hardware.

Comment: I guess so in general when you don't know the details of the hardware or it's sufficiently complex. But this was supposed to be an easy textbook exercise =(

Comment: For textbook exercise, it's fine as long as it matches what's at the back of the book. :P But 90% of the time, the real-life numbers will be completely different.

Comment: Now I am a little busy, later if no one answers this, I would provide a simple analysis. Like Mysticial said, real world could be more complicated, but understanding the principle does get paid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**How data are stored in memory**
Every structure `pos` has a size of 8 Bytes, thus the total size of `pos[16][16]` is 2048 Bytes. And the order of the array are as follows:
`pos[0][0]` `pos[0][1]` `pos[0][2]` ...... `pos[0][15]` `pos[1]0[]` ...... `pos[1][15]`.......`pos[15][0]` ......`pos[15][15]`

**The cache organization compared to the data**
For the cache, each block is 16 Bytes, which is the same size as two elements of the array. The Entire cache is 1024 Bytes, which is half the size of the entire array. Since cache is direct-mapped, that means if we label the cache block from 0 to 63, we can safely assume that the mapping should look like this
------------   memory----------------------------cache
`pos[0][0]` `pos[0][1]`  ----------->   `block 0`
`pos[0][2]` `pos[0][3]`  ----------->   `block 1`
`pos[0][4]` `pos[0][5]`  ----------->   `block 2`
`pos[0][14]` `pos[0][15]`  -------->   `block 7`
.......
`pos[1][0]` `pos[1][1]`  ----------->   `block 8`
`pos[1][2]` `pos[1][3]`  ----------->   `block 9`
.......
`pos[7][14]` `pos[7][15]`  -------->   `block 63`
`pos[8][0]` `pos[8][1]`  ----------->   `block 0`
.......
`pos[15][14]` `pos[15][15]`  ----->   `block 63`

**How `function1` manipulates memory**
The loop follows a column-wise inner loop, that means the first iteration loads `pos[0][0]` and `pos[0][1]` to cache `block 0`, the second iteration loads `pos[1][0]` and `pos[1][1]` to cache `block 8`. Caches are **cold**, so the first column `x` is always **miss**, while `y` is always hit. The second column data are supposedly all loaded in cache during the first column access, but this is **NOT** the case. Since `pos[8][0]` access has already evict the former `pos[0][0]` page(they both map to `block 0`!).So on, the miss rate is 50%.

**How `function2` manipulates memory**
The second function has nice **stride-1** access pattern. That means when accessing `pos[0][0].x` `pos[0][0].y` `pos[0][1].x` `pos[0][1].y` only the first one is a miss due to the cold cache. The following patterns are all the same. So the miss rate is only 25%.

K-way associative cache follows the same analysis, although that may be more tedious. For getting the most out of the cache system, try to initiate a nice access pattern, say `stride-1`, and use the data as much as possible during each loading from memory. Real world cpu microarchitecture employs other intelligent design and algorithm to enhance the efficiency. The best method is always to measure the time in real world, dump the core code, and do a thorough analysis.

Comment: Very well explained, now I understand where I was wrong (because of the direct mapping the second, forth etc. columns get overwritten). My answer would apply to >2-associative caches I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my computer science lectures are a bit far off but I think I figured it out (it's actually a very easy example when you think about it).

Your struct is 8 byte long (2 x 4). Since your cache blocks are 16 bytes, a memory access `grid[i][j]` will fetch exactly two struct entries (`grid[i][j]` and `grid[i][j+1]`). Therefore, if you loop through the second index only every 4th access will lead to a memory read. If you loop through the first index, you probably throw away the second entry that has been fetched, that depends on the number of fetches in the inner loop vs. the overall cache-size though.

Now we have to think about the cache size as well: You say that you have 64 lines that are directly mapped. In function 1, an inner loop is 16 fetches. That means, the 17th fetch you get to grid[j][i+1]. This should actually be a hit, since it should have been kept in the cache since the last inner loop walk. Every second inner loop should therefore only consist of hits.

Well, if my reasonings are correct, the answer that has been given to you should be wrong. Both functions should perform with 25% misses. Maybe someone finds a better answer but if you understand my reasoning I'd ask a TA about that.

**Edit:** Thinking about it again, we should first define what actually qualifies as a miss/hit. When you look at

```
total_x += grid[j][i].x;
total_y += grid[j][i].y;
```

are these defined as two memory accesses or one? A decent compiler with optimization settings should optimize this to

```
pos temp = grid[j][i];
total_x += temp.x;
total_y += temp.y;
```

which could be counted as one memory access. I therefore propose the universal answer to all CS questions: "It depends."